# XSS with URL encoding

Tags: xss, encoding, waf, reflected-xss, filtering

If a website URL gets encoded then is the website still vulnerable to XSS or no?

For example, if I try `<script>alert(1)</script>` and the site URL encodes my payload to `%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C%2Fscript%3E` does this mean the site is vulnerable to XSS or no?

Comment: The answer depends on what the webapplication does with the URL-encoded payload. Are you assuming a scenario of the type `echo urlencode(payload)`?

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on how the page renders your payload.

If the target is a HTML page and the payload still appears as `<script>alert(1)</script>`, an XSS will occur, assuming no CSP or Chrome's XSS auditor. However, if the HTML page renders your payload in the URL syntax i.e. `%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C%2Fscript%3E`, there won't be an XSS. Depending on where the payload is injected in the latter, I would also try special characters like `"` and `'` to try escape the URL context to inject directly into the HTML (url) tag.

Comment: The ``htmlentities()`` function and the ``htmlspecialchars()`` function, both of which I believe to be used in this parameter, will not allow escaping.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular example, that parameter would not be vulnerable to XSS.

It does depend, you aren't giving a load of information, but generally speaking that seems to be something like: `htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($input))` which is incredibly safe.

This does not mean that the **SITE** is not vulnerable, it just means that this parameter in particular seems to be safe.

This still depends, is the parameter injecting your input into a link, iframe, image, etc? If it is injecting within another element, it may be possible regardless using methods such as `javascript:` and `data:`.

Comment: Actually my xss payloads was reflected on the page. The site Url encode my payloads like  %3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C%2Fscript%3E

Comment: In that case, they are using the ``htmlentities()`` function, but are printing it raw, which means it is also going through a function such as ``htmlspecialchars()``. This is not possible to get XSS in the way you described. Doesn't mean the entire site is secure, but it does mean this parameter would be.